# EL&U Blog, the reboot

Tags: discussion, blog

We have a [blog](http://english.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1). We've had it for a while. You should take a look, there is some great content. I'll wait here while you read it...

Good, no?

This is a call for regular contributors. You don't have to have an idea immediately, just a willingness to write coherently about English and EL&U. If you do have ideas that's even better, because that's bound to be more interesting.

The plan is simple in its elegance. We are aiming to publish an article every two weeks. To achieve this I will wrangle, cajole and encourage some willing contributors to write posts on the following (negotiable) topics:

- English Language tools (online and offline)
- Plurals involving groups
- Plurals involving fractions
- Possessive apostrophes
- Subjunctive mood
- Gender neutral pronouns
- The journey of a word from being two (or more) words to being one.
- The use of "that that"
- Formulating good [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) questions
- Prepositions at the end of sentences
- Me vs Myself vs I
- That vs Which

There is no particular order to the topics. I think 12 is enough to get started so we can see if the blog still has legs. If you have more topics you'd like to add (or do instead), that is fantastic.

The schedule would be to get the first post up on 1st September and then post something new fortnightly. I am going to be holding a weekly chat in the [blog's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063/elu-blog) to discuss what should be posted, catchup on progress and help with any issues. If you have questions about the blog, I will be there a lot of the time (I do sleep, though) and I will respond to pings when I get them.

If you don't want to contribute directly we can always use other help, as in copy editors, morale boosters and idea suppliers.

I'm not averse to someone wanting to contribute a one-off post, but at this point we're really looking for regulars.

So

A. who wants to contribute?
B. when is a good time for a weekly chat?

## Come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063/elu-blog) to discuss the blog

We need more contributors.

Comment: Congratulations, this makes me very excited! I'd like assist in this 'venture' and would like to make a contribution for sharing English grammar with you; but, I noticed the absence of an outline of the editorial process involved in that blog.-

Comment: I'd be excited to write for an audience like this. But these topics – aren't they pretty much nattered to death every week? What's left to say? What does the blog format offer, except an opportunity to express one's prejudices more frankly?

Comment: @StoneyB — Feel free to suggest other topics, pretty much anything is acceptable so long as it's related to English or the site. I picked those because they are frequently asked questions, so posts on them would be most beneficial to our user base.

Comment: @StoneyB You should come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063/elu-blog) to discuss topics and such

Comment: "No man but a blockhead ever wrote, except for money." — Samuel Johnson, attr. by Boswell

Comment: @Robusto — I don't write for free. I write for Freedom.

Comment: @MattЭллен: Doesn't matter. The pay is the same.

Comment: @MattЭллен Is there any way to see how many people view a particular blog post?

Comment: @Luke — There is, but only for the blog admins. I can tell you, you're performing on par with the other posts, if that's of any help?

Comment: It appears to be part of a different SE, since it wanted me to log in to comment, and then refused to recognize my ELU or Ling login.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, the blog sites are wordpress sites, so the logins have to be transfered, as if you were logging into a different SE site for the first time. Robusto is having [a similar problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156400/login-authentication-isnt-acknowledging-an-existing-openid), so it might help if you report your problem too.

Comment: Is there a form to fill out?

Comment: @JohnLawler sorry, I mean just post an answer to the question with your problem symptoms

Comment: Comments don't count, then? Strange asymmetries here. I find the comments much more substantive and useful than the Official Answers.

Comment: @JohnLawler I mean an answer to Robusto's question. I can't fix the technical problems with the blog, unfortunately. But if you put an answer on that question it'll get more attention than a comment would.

Comment: Good. All I have to do is find where Robusto's question is. And succeed in logging in if it's not here. And then write an Official Answer to it. And that will attract the attention of the Powers That Be? Maybe I'm happier not attracting so much attention, thanks. I am no fan of Powers That Be.

Comment: @JohnLawler I lunk to the question in my first reply to you.

Comment: Well, It's really GraceNote's question but asked on behalf of Robusto.

Comment: Thank you. I found it. I also found that "You must log in to answer this question." Recursion worse recounted.

Comment: @MattЭллен:  "I 'lunk'?"  ;-)

Comment: Would love to have time to contribute! Two ideas for articles that occurred to me just while reading this was on the use of whom vs who and in the same vein as "that that" - "had had" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher

Comment: oh! oh! A third idea, if someone was interested, an article on the prolifigate neologisms of the poet John Milton (or any other fun neologisms for that matter, personally I just like saying "neologisms")

Comment: Ooh, I'd love to get creative and propose the mother of all gender neutral pronouns. Oops :D

Comment: @MattE.Эллен As the keeper of the blog, what do you think about [this suggestion](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7692/blog-as-canonical-repository)?

Answer (score 11):

OK! Kit's rallying got a lot more interested than is represented in the other answers.

I have scheduled [a regular chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1063/elu-blog?tab=schedule) to be every Thursday at 15:00 GMT. This is not set in stone, but it is the easiest time for me!

We have several topics in the pipeline now.

- How to write good [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) questions — [Mahnax](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11550/mahnax) ✓
- Typography part 1 — [cornbread ninja](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18399/cornbread-ninja) ✓
- Prescriptivism vs Descriptivism — [Cameron](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/19644/cameron) ✓
- Possessive apostrophes' — [KitFox♦](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8360/kitfox) ✓
- English words with Nordic roots — [Luke](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/24168/luke) ✓
- That vs Which — [StoneyB](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/24489/stoneyb) ✓
- Explain to new users what they should do if their question is closed as General Reference — [StoneyB](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/24489/stoneyb) ✓
- EL&U chat — [me](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3559/matt) ✓
- Subjunctive — [tchrist](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist)
- A few, Some, Several, etc. — TBD
- Pirate English — TBD
- A review of Strunk & White's EoS — TBD
- Use and misuse of Google Ngrams — TBD
- English language tools — TBD
- Typography part 2 — [cornbread ninja](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18399/cornbread-ninja)
- Gender neutral pronouns — TBD
- What constitutes a word in English — TBD
- Something about ELL — [J.R.](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18220/j-r)

Other than Mahnax being first, there isn't a particular order to the posts.

Comment: I'll update this as I hear more from other potential contributers

Comment: Do the above topics include coverage of  subject-verb number agreement, forming plurals, and (so to speak) tense ?

Comment: Subjunctive YES! Same for typography. Yay @cornbread ninja Only issue with typography is that I don't know if it on-topic for EL&U, there was a question about that matter a long time ago. Regardless, I want to see typography as an EL&U blog post topic, very much. I think typography **can** be appropriate content for EL&U, and it is beautiful and a favorite hobby interest of mine, and many other people.

Comment: @jwpat7 if you have a post in mind, come to [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063/elu-blog) and pitch it. We can see how it compares to Mitch's.

Comment: @MattЭллен, the items I mentioned are among those that appear so often in elementary questions that ELU might benefit from authoritative articles discussing them.  However, I don't know how such posts should be organized.

Comment: @jwpat7 - you should give it a go anyway! I can help with organisation, if you like.

Comment: We need that apostrophe in " Possessive apostrophes' — KitFox♦ " ?

Comment: English words with Nordic roots. Yes! You'll find them in everything known and common up until the 16th century. Merriam touched on why several goose are geese and not 'gooses' or 'goose'. Smith is from the Danish 'smed', 'iron' and 'järn' are sound-alikes, and so on. Category words like 'bird' (ancient word fugol/fågel) are genuine English inventions, and the reasons are obvious. You'll find most of them come from Danish and Swedish, not so much Norway. An Englishmen hearing Danish spoken today may think he's hearing English until he catches on, the manner of speaking is similar to this day.

Answer (score 6):

Would you accept posts recycled from my own blog?

Comment: Hi Barrie. Yeah, we'd love those. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Perhaps we could make featured posts that link back to you original content?

Comment: My current blog is here http://realgrammar.posterous.com/ and there’s an earlier one here http://grammarforgrownups.wordpress.com/. I'm open to suggestions as to how they might best fit the EL&U blog format.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, I can't access both links.

Comment: They are no longer active, but I have a blog/website at https://caxton1485.wordpress.com/.

Answer (score 5):

Yay, Matt! I'm on board for moral support and copy editing. Also, coffee and donuts.

I can hang out in chat most days anywhere from 0800 - 1500 Eastern Time (UTC-5).

Thank you for volunteering to step up and try to get our blog jumpstarted.

Comment: Thanks, Kit! Your support means a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great idea! A blog holds the site together and keeps users in touch and interested. I'd love to help in my spare time.

However, I don't know if I'm a loner, but I don't feel *qualified* to write about the English language in a blog read by 21,000+ users every other week.

I am fine with copy-editing, though.

Comment: You should come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063/elu-blog) to discuss the blog.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea. Blogs and forums are a good idea, but they have one weak point. There are a lot of interesting questions, answers and ideas in forums and in blogger sites, but they vanish in the course of time and you can't find things one has read some time ago. It's almost impossible to find such things again.
There should be ways to make the contents of forums and blogger sites transparent and there should be index-lists and registers so one can find things one is interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Will they have to be solid hard and fast rules, or is there room to talk about the evolution of the language, and areas of ambiguity, or looser rules?  I'd love to contribute some thoughts on elements of style.

Comment: I'm not sure which rules you're referring too. I'd be very happy to have a post on Elements of Style.